# Middle element in Binary search python

Tags: python, data-structures

In python binary search to find the mid value i use:

```
mid=math.ceil((high+low)/2).
```

Is `ceil` more optimal or should I use `floor` or `round`?

Answer (score 1):

for the algorithm there is no difference in performance, i think the only difference is in the cost of the operation, floor should be the easiest one because the computer doesn't need to do anything except remove the floating point part.

Comment: In general [not specific to python] which one can i use, ceil or floor?

Comment: you can use both, just remember that in some case for example with low=0 and high=1 you can get stuck there forever so you have to check that the low and high are changed since the last cycle. there is no performance difference.